# Compare two filenames in different folders

Tags: python, string, split

I have two files in different locations: `/tmp/helpers_image.tif` and `/tmp/outputs/helpers_image.qml`. I want to compare their names before the extension.

How can I compare the files in the those two folders?

If these files were in the same folder I could use:

```
t1 = 'helpers_image.qml'
t1_list= t1.split('.') 
t1_list[0] == t2_list[0]
```

...assuming the other list would be called `t2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the `os.path.basename` function to get the name of the files no matter in which folders they are. Here you go:

```
import os

filename1 = os.path.basename('/tmp/helpers_image.tif')  # returns 'helpers_image.tif'
filename2 = os.path.basename('/tmp/outputs/helpers_image.qml') # return 'helpers_image.qml'

# Thanks to Cyrbil for noticing a bug here
name1 = filename1.rsplit('.', 1)[0]  # returns 'helpers_image'
name2 = filename2.rsplit('.', 1)[0]  # return 'helpers_image'

if name1 == name2:  # This is True for this exact case
    # your logic here
```

Another way is as [suggested by **Dunes**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855664/compare-two-filenames-in-different-folders-python/31855792#comment51631104_31855792):

```
name1 = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext('/tmp/helpers_image.tif')[0])
name2 = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext('/tmp/outputs/helpers_image.qml')[0])
```

Comment: You might want to rework the split as for filename like `my.file.txt` it wont work. `'my.file.txt'.rsplit('.', 1)[0]`

Comment: As well as `rsplit` there is also `os.path.splitext`.

Comment: `os.path.splitext(path)`, surely?

Comment: Dunes answer ok. But don't work with filenames, (+don't encode filename use dir(s))

Answer (score 3):

In addition to that, if you find that you need to match multiple file names then you can use sets.

```
files1 = ['helpers_image1.qml', 'helpers_image2.qml', 'helpers_image3.qml', 'helpers_imag4.qml']
files2 = ['helpers_image2.qml', 'helpers_image3.qml']
print set(files1).intersection( set(files2) )
```

Outputs:

> set(['helpers_image3.qml', 'helpers_image2.qml'])

Comment: "*I want to compare their names before the extension*"

Comment: Oops thanks for that! Cyrbil's answer is just fine then.

Comment: Upvote for answering the wrong question, which happened to be my current one. NOICE!